# Jira POST & PUT Rest Calls return Error 400 from Python

Tags: python, rest, python-requests, jira, jira-rest-api

I'm encountering a really strange issue with the Jira Rest API - whever I try to create an issue using a POST request or update one with a PUT request to jira/rest/api/latest/issue/ I receive Error code 400 from Python 2.7 requests but it succeeds from Powershell's Invoke Web Request.

However I'm able to pull information from the Jira server using GET requests, including:

- The list of Projects
- The list of IssueTypes
- The list of Custom Fields
- The Issues of a given type for a given project
- The Zephyr Plugin's Test Executions
- The Zephyr Plugin's Test Cycles

I've tried a number of troubleshooting suggestions from similar topics from the Atlassian support site already:

- I've verified that the Authorisation is correct (it's also required for the GET requests which all work)
- I'm testing with an account that has administrator level access to the Jira instance
- I've stripped the json back to just the fields and format matching the REST API documentation here: [jira-rest-api-examples/#creating-an-issue-examples](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/jira-rest-api-examples/#creating-an-issue-examples)
- I've ensured that all the relevant session cookie and header data is stored and added to the follw-up requests
- I've verified through Issue/createmeta that I have the capabilities to create that issue type (and as I pointed out earlier - it works in Powershell)
- I've tried using Issuetype name and id as well as project key and id as the identifier, neither one changes anything
- I've even tried both omitting and including the trailing slash on the /issue path in case that was important
- I've verified that it's not a case of Python's user-agent being blocked for POST/PUT requests

Json Body (Raw):

```
{"fields": {"issuetype": {"id": "10702"}, "project": {"id": "10061"}, "description": "Execution for Issue: SDBX-859", "summary": "Execution for Issue: SDBX-859"}}
```

(Formatted for Legibility):

```
{
    "fields": {
        "issuetype": {
            "id": "10702"
        },
        "project": {
            "id": "10061"
        },
        "description": "Execution for Issue: SDBX-859",
        "summary": "Execution for Issue: SDBX-859"
    }
}
```

The process flow starts with this class:

```
class Migrator(object):
    RestURLs = {
        "projects": "api/latest/project",
        "issuetype": "api/latest/issuetype",
        "fields": "api/latest/field",
        "tests": "api/latest/search?maxResults={limit}&expand=meta&jql=IssueType='{testType}'+and+project={projectKey}",
        "zSteps": "zapi/latest/teststep/{issueId}",
        "zExecutions": "zapi/latest/zql/executeSearch?zqlQuery=project={projectKey}",
        "zCycles": "zapi/latest/cycle?projectId={projectId}",
        "issue": "api/latest/issue/{issueKey}",
        "xSteps": "raven/1.0/api/test/{issueKey}/step/{stepId}",
        "xSet": "raven/1.0/api/testset/{issueKey}/test",
        "xExecution": "raven/1.0/api/testexec/{issueKey}/test"
    }

    CustomFields = {
        "Zephyr Teststep": "",
        "Manual Test Steps": "",
        "Test Type": ""
    }

    IssueNames = {
        "zephyr":"Zephyr - Test",
        "xray":"Test",
        "set":"Test Set",
        "execution":"Test Execution"
    }
    IssueTypes = {}

def __init__(self):
    self.results = []
    print("new Migrator initialised")
    self.restHandler = RestHandler()
    self.baseURL = "http://127.0.0.1/jira/rest/"
    self.authentication = ""
    self.commonHeaders = {}
    self.projectList = []
    self.project = None
    self.testList = []
    self.executionList = {}
    self.versionList = set()
    self.cycleList = {}
    self.setList = []

def connect(self, username, password, serverUrl="http://127.0.0.1"):
    # 1 - connect to jira
    if serverUrl[-1] != '/':
        serverUrl += '/'
    self.baseURL = str.format("{0}jira/rest/", serverUrl)
    self.authentication = "Basic " + base64.b64encode(username + ":" + password)
    self.commonHeaders = {"Authorization": self.authentication}

    print("Connecting to Server: " + self.baseURL)
    headers = self.commonHeaders
    projList = self.restHandler.perform(method=HTTP.GET,url=self.baseURL,path=Migrator.RestURLs["projects"],headers=headers)

    # 2 - populate projects list
    for projDict in projList:
        self.projectList.append(Project().fromDict(projDict))
```

from this method:

```
    def migrateExecutions(self, project):
        print "working..."
        for execution in self.executionList:
            # Restricting it only to my issues for testing...
            if execution.assigneeUserName == "boydnic":
                headers = self.commonHeaders
                execData = {"fields":{}}
                execData["fields"]["issuetype"] = {"id":self.IssueTypes[self.IssueNames["execution"]].id}
                execData["fields"]["project"] = {"id":project.id}
#                execData["fields"]["reporter"] = {"name": userName}
#                execData["fields"]["assignee"] = {"name": execution.assigneeUserName}
                execData["fields"]["summary"] = "Execution for Issue: " + execution.issueKey
                execData["fields"]["description"] = execution.comment if execution.comment else execData["fields"]["summary"]

                xrayExec = self.createIssue(execData)
                self.results.append(self.restHandler.perform(method=HTTP.POST, url=self.baseURL,
                                         path=self.RestURLs["xExecution"], urlData={"issueKey":xrayExec.key},
                                         headers=headers, body={"add":[execution.issueKey]}))
```

to this Method:

```
def createIssue(self, issueTemplate):
    result = self.restHandler.perform(method=HTTP.POST, url=self.baseURL, path=Migrator.RestURLs["issue"], urlData={"issueKey":""}, headers=self.commonHeaders, body=issueTemplate)
    issue = Issue()
    issue.id = result["id"]
    issue.key = result["key"]
    issue.self = result["self"]
    print("Created Issue: "+issue.key)
    return issue
```

Which itself calls this class:

```
class RestHandler(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.headerStore = {'X-CITNET-USER':"",
                            'X-ASEN':"",
                            'X-ASESSIONID':"",
                            'X-AUSERNAME':""}
        self.cookieJar = requests.cookies.RequestsCookieJar()

    def perform(self, method, url, path, headers={}, urlData={"projectId": "", "projectKey": "", "issueId": "", "issueKey": ""},
                formData=dict(), body=""):
        resultData = "{}"
        path = url + path.format(**urlData)
        body = body if isinstance(body, str) else json.dumps(body)
        if self.headerStore:
            headers.update(self.headerStore)
        jar = self.cookieJar
        print(str(method))
        print(path)
        if method is HTTP.GET:
            resultData = requests.get(path, headers=headers, cookies = jar)
        elif method is HTTP.POST:
            print (body)
            path = path.rstrip('/')
            resultData = requests.post(path, json=body, headers=headers, cookies = jar)
        elif method is HTTP.PUT:
            print (body)
            resultData = requests.put(path, json=body, headers=headers, cookies = jar)
        elif method is HTTP.DELETE:
            request = "DELETE request to " + path
        else:
            raise TypeError
        print("\n\n===============================\nRest Call Debugging\n===============================")
        print(resultData)
        print(resultData.url)
        print(resultData.status_code)
        print(resultData.headers)
        print(resultData.content)
        print("\n\n===============================\n/Rest Call Debugging\n==============================")
        if 199 < resultData.status_code < 300:
            for hKey, hValue in resultData.headers.iteritems():
                if hKey in self.headerStore.keys():
                    self.headerStore[hKey] = hValue
            self.cookieJar.update(resultData.cookies)
            print "testing breakpoint"
            return json.loads(resultData.content)
        else:
            raise IOError(resultData.reason)
```

The Debugging Section included in the Rest Handler class just spits out the following:

```
===============================
Rest Call Debugging
===============================
https://webgate.test.ec.europa.eu/CITnet/jira/rest/api/latest/issue
400
{'X-AUSERNAME': 'boydnic', 'X-AREQUESTID': '<redacted>', 'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'Set-Cookie': 'crowd.token_key=""; Expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:10 GMT; Path=/; HttpOnly, crowd.token_key=<redacted>; Path=/; HttpOnly, JSESSIONID=<redacted>; Path=/CITnet/jira; HttpOnly, atlassian.xsrf.token=<redacted>; Path=/CITnet/jira', 'X-Seraph-LoginReason': 'OUT, OK', 'X-ASEN': '<redacted>', 'X-CITNET-USER': 'boydnic', 'Connection': 'Keep-Alive', 'X-ASESSIONID': '<redacted>', 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, no-store, no-transform, proxy-revalidate', 'Date': 'Tue, 24 Apr 2018 08:29:16 GMT', 'Server': 'Apache-Coyote/1.1', 'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'}
{"errorMessages":["Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, class com.atlassian.jira.rest.v2.issue.IssueUpdateBean] from JSON String; no single-String constructor/factory method"]}


===============================
/Rest Call Debugging
==============================
```

With this I/O error intermingled with it:

(I disentangled the STD and ERR streams for this post)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"C:/Users/BOYDnic/Documents/migrator/issueMigrator.py", line 546, in
<module> <Response [400]>
    jiraMigrator.migrate(projectKey)
      File "C:/Users/BOYDnic/Documents/migrator/issueMigrator.py", line 330, in migrate
    self.migrateExecutions(project)   File "C:/Users/BOYDnic/Documents/migrator/issueMigrator.py", line 475, in
migrateExecutions
    xrayExec = self.createIssue(execData)   File "C:/Users/BOYDnic/Documents/migrator/issueMigrator.py", line 334, in
createIssue
    result = self.restHandler.perform(method=HTTP.POST, url=self.baseURL, path=Migrator.RestURLs["issue"],
urlData={"issueKey":""}, headers=self.commonHeaders,
body=issueTemplate)   File
"C:/Users/BOYDnic/Documents/migrator/issueMigrator.py", line 84, in
perform
    raise IOError(resultData.reason) IOError: Bad Request
```

I'm getting incredibly frustrated by this, not least because it's blocking the completion of this migration script and seems to make no sense.

Comment: Could you past the raw http request which fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that it was my use of `json.dumps(body)` in combination with `put(..., json=body, ...)` causing the issue.

Using the json keyword tells Requests to serialize the string again, escaping the " marks to \" and wrapping it in quotes again.

Effectively:

```
{"fields": {"issuetype": {"id": 10702},"project": {"id":10061},"description": "","summary": "Execution for Issue: SDBX-859"}}
```

Became:

```
"{\"fields\": {\"issuetype\": {\"id\": \"10702\"}, \"project\": {\"id\": \"10061\"}, \"description\": \"Execution for Issue: SDBX-859\", \"summary\": \"Execution for Issue: SDBX-859\"}}"
```

Use `body=json.dumps({...})` with a manually set content header or `json={...}` not both.

Answer (score 1):

Jira returns errors like "Can not instantiate value of type ..." when the request body is incorrectly formatted. In your case, you provided a string where Jira expects a more complex content (typically a dict).

Comment: Cheers for responding, the body of the POST request was initially more complex (included Reporter and Assignee) but I trimmed it back to match the structure of the bare basics example body given in the Jira Rest documentation (linked above).